Error generating build on ios in my react native app
I have a react native + expo app which works perfectly on Android and Expo go, but when I want to compile in Xcode it gives me this error
/Users/edwin/Desktop/App/app-riqueza/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/gRPC-C++/gRPC-C++-dummy.m module map file '/Users/edwin/Desktop/App/app-riqueza/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/grpc/gRPC-Core.modulemap' not found

In terms of the IOS environment, they are quite incompetent and I have solved errors in the Podfile and this is how my file is currently
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"`), "scripts/autolinking")
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"`), "scripts/react_native_pods")

require 'json'
podfile_properties = JSON.parse(File.read(File.join(__dir__, 'Podfile.properties.json'))) rescue {}

ENV['RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED'] = podfile_properties['newArchEnabled'] == 'true' ? '1' : '0'
ENV['EX_DEV_CLIENT_NETWORK_INSPECTOR'] = podfile_properties['EX_DEV_CLIENT_NETWORK_INSPECTOR']

use_autolinking_method_symbol = ('use' + '_native' + '_modules!').to_sym
origin_autolinking_method = self.method(use_autolinking_method_symbol)
self.define_singleton_method(use_autolinking_method_symbol) do |*args|
  if ENV['EXPO_UNSTABLE_CORE_AUTOLINKING'] == '1'
    Pod::UI.puts('Using expo-modules-autolinking as core autolinking source'.green)
    config_command = [
      'node',
      '--no-warnings',
      '--eval',
      'require(require.resolve(\'expo-modules-autolinking\', { paths: [require.resolve(\'expo/package.json\')] }))(process.argv.slice(1))',
      'react-native-config',
      '--json',
      '--platform',
      'ios'
    ]
    origin_autolinking_method.call(config_command)
  else
    origin_autolinking_method.call()
  end
end

platform :ios, podfile_properties['ios.deploymentTarget'] || '13.4'
use_modular_headers!
pod 'gRPC-Core', :modular_headers => true
pod 'gRPC-C++', :modular_headers => true
pod 'BoringSSL-GRPC', :modular_headers => true
install! 'cocoapods',
  :deterministic_uuids => false

prepare_react_native_project!

target 'Seminario' do
  use_expo_modules!
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_frameworks! :linkage => podfile_properties['ios.useFrameworks'].to_sym if podfile_properties['ios.useFrameworks']
  use_frameworks! :linkage => ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS'].to_sym if ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    :hermes_enabled => podfile_properties['expo.jsEngine'] == nil || podfile_properties['expo.jsEngine'] == 'hermes',
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/..",
    :privacy_file_aggregation_enabled => podfile_properties['apple.privacyManifestAggregationEnabled'] != 'false',
  )

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      config[:reactNativePath],
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false,
      :ccache_enabled => podfile_properties['apple.ccacheEnabled'] == 'true',
    )

    # This is necessary for Xcode 14, because it signs resource bundles by default
    # when building for devices.
    installer.target_installation_results.pod_target_installation_results
      .each do |pod_name, target_installation_result|
      target_installation_result.resource_bundle_targets.each do |resource_bundle_target|
        resource_bundle_target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
        end
      end
    end

    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if target.name == 'BoringSSL-GRPC'
        target.source_build_phase.files.each do |file|
          if file.settings && file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS']
            flags = file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'].split
            flags.reject! { |flag| flag == '-GCC_WARN_INHIBIT_ALL_WARNINGS' }
            file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'] = flags.join(' ')
          end
        end
      end
    end

  end

  post_integrate do |installer|
    begin
      expo_patch_react_imports!(installer)
    rescue => e
      Pod::UI.warn e
    end
  end
end

I had to add the lines
use_modular_headers!
pod 'gRPC-Core', :modular_headers => true
pod 'gRPC-C++', :modular_headers => true
pod 'BoringSSL-GRPC', :modular_headers => true

To solve previous errors, but now there is this one that I have not been able to solve, does anyone know how I can fix it?
